# Auto update HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I have an HTML table wherein the data displayed came from my google spreadsheet. What I want is for when I update my google sheet the table on the HTML will automatically update without refreshing the whole page. Can anyone help me? Thanks. Also, when new data is added, it will change the background color to red.

Here's the code on my Code.gs:

**

```
function getData1(){
  var spreadSheetId = ""; //spreadsheet ID
  var dataRange     = "Data!A2:N"; //CHANGE
 
  var range   = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId,dataRange);
  var values  = range.values;
  Logger.log(values);
  return values;
}
```

**

```js
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData1();
  setInterval(function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
        columns: [
          {"title":"Task"},
          {"title":"Pending"},
          {"title":"Completed"},
          {"title":"Link",
          "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
              data = '<a href="' + data + '" target="_blank">' + data + '</a>';
            }
            return data;
          }
        }
        ]
      }, 1000 );
    });
  })
```

```css
#datatable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

#datatable td,
#data-table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#datatable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#datatable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#datatable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
```

Comment: Without updating the page, you would need to do a HTTP request to a server that would return you the table information from time to time, and then in your javascript just check if anythign changed

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to that :<

Comment: just so I understand, you use the getData1 function to get the user data, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want, Here is an example: Initially, the table is empty and will be populated with data fetched from the `Google Spreadsheet` using the `fetchData()` function. The `updateTable()` function updates the `HTML` table with the new data and changes the background color of new rows to red:

```js
// Define a function to fetch data from Google Spreadsheet
function fetchData() {
  var spreadsheetId = "your-spreadsheet-id"; // Change to your spreadsheet ID
  var range = "Data!A2:N"; // Change to the range of your data
  var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + "/values/" + range + "?key=YOUR_API_KEY";
  // Change YOUR_API_KEY to your API key

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => updateTable(data.values))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

// Define a function to update the HTML table
function updateTable(dataArray) {
  var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
  table.clear();
  table.rows.add(dataArray);
  table.draw();

  // Change the background color of new rows to red
  var rows = table.rows({order:'index'}).nodes();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    if (!$(row).hasClass('new-row')) {
      $(row).addClass('new-row');
      $(row).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  }
}

// Call fetchData() initially and every 5 seconds
fetchData();
setInterval(fetchData, 5000);
```

```css
#datatable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

#datatable td,
#datatable th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#datatable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#datatable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#datatable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}

#datatable tr.new-row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Table Example</title>
  <!-- Include jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include DataTables library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Pending</th>
        <th>Completed</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- Table rows will be added dynamically -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should I put the FetchData code on the gs? or on the HTML? and where can I see the API key? :<

Comment: The administrator blocked the site where I can generate the API key :< Is there an alternative code not using API key?